# Rendered mode option missing in user interface

Tags: interface

The rendered mode option us missing in my user interface. So far, I only get these options: object mode, edit mode, sculpt mode, vertex paint, weight paint, texture paint, but no rendered mode!
This whenever I am in render, game engine or cycles, whith whatever environment (game logic, default, and so on).
I have reseted my user interface to factory settings already, but it didn't help.
I suppose there is an option in the user preferences panel, but I haven't found anything yet.
I use the 2.77a release.
here are screenshots of thr issue :

[image: rendered mode missing]
[image: option missing]

Thank you in advance !

Comment: What happens if you use the current version of blender from blender.org?

Comment: Could it be that you choosed Blender Game engine? There won't be Rendered shading. Choose Cycles or Blender Internal, it should be present. Then try pressing Shift+Z as well while in viewport.  Make sure to download Blender from official resource as well (blender.org).

Comment: Indeed! I was in BGE. I also thought there was a rendered mode in the first menu, which I reckon it was probably false. Anyway, thank you both for your answers!